# Using React and Redux, how would you clear an input field after a successful redux-thunk completion?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Let's say you are using `react` and `redux` and you have the following elements on a page:

- Input field to write something
- A save button to write your text async to the DB

The expected flow is that the save button should dispatch a `save` redux thunk to handle the async behaviour of the save. So far, so good.

But there's an extra tricky requirement:

- Upon save success, the input should be cleared.

I think that there are a couple of ways to handle this:

---

### OPTION 1

- Add the controlled input state to your Redux store

This is the easiest one. Basically you'll add the `input` state to your Redux store and when you thunk dispatch the `SAVE_SUCCESS` action, your reducer will respond with something like this:

```
SAVE_SUCCESS(state, action) {
  state.inputValue = '';
}
```

The downside of this is that you'll have to dispatch an action on every key stroke, and that is going to flood your Redux devTools inspector.

---

### OPTION 2

- Have a controlled input using React local state
- Pass an `clearInput` function (using `useCallback`) to your save `thunk`

Something like this:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('initialVale');
const clearInput = useCallback(() => setInputValue(''),[]);

const onClick = dispatch(saveThunk({clearInput});
```

So, from the thunk you would do something like:

```
const { clearInput } = thunkProps;
await saveToDB();
clearInput(); // THIS COMES FROM THE thunkProps
```

---

### OPTION 3

- Same as option 2 but with an uncontrolled input (so, no state at all)
- Pass the input ref element to your thunk

So, from the thunk you would do something like:

```
const { inputRef } = thunkProps;
await saveToDB();
inputRef.current.value = '';
```

---

**QUESTION**

Which one would you go for and why? And also, is there a better approach to this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for awaiting the promise from the thunk in the component, and setting component state there, as shown in our tutorials:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns#thunks-and-promises
- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#checking-thunk-results-in-components

Example:

```js
  const handleKeyDown = async e => {
    // If the user pressed the Enter key:
    const trimmedText = text.trim()
    if (e.which === 13 && trimmedText) {
      // Create and dispatch the thunk function itself
      setStatus('loading')
      // Wait for the promise returned by saveNewTodo
      await dispatch(saveNewTodo(trimmedText))
      // And clear out the text input
      setText('')
      setStatus('idle')
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I usually wrap my thunk code in a `try...catch`, so I can dispatch the `ASYNC_ACTION_FAILURE()` action from the thunk's `catch` block. If I choose to await for the `thunk` to complete from the component, how can I know if the thunk has completed successfully or if it has failed? Should I re-throw from the thunk's catch block?

Comment: My main suggestion there would be to use [Redux Toolkit's `createAsyncThunk` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk), which will do that "success/failure" action dispatching for you entirely.  You can then do `dispatch(myAsyncThunk()).unwrap()` to convert the result back into a value or thrown error, per that "Essentials" page and https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions .

Comment: Thanks, again, Mark! Tbh, I've known about the `createAsyncThunk` function for a while now, but I've never used it. What always drove me off from it was the `extraReducers: (builder) => { builder.addCase(someThunk.fulfilled, ... }` pattern. I feel much more in control when I'm creating my own async-lifecycle actions and handling them in the regular case reducers. Ex: `SAVE_START`, `SAVE_SUCCESS` and `SAVE_FAILURE`. Maybe I should start using it, though. Big thanks for improving the documentation. It's been a while since I've read it. I should definitely read it again.

Comment: Yeah, you're really _not_ saving much by hand-defining the actions yourself (even if you're using `createSlice` for those), and `createAsyncThunk` has several additional useful properties around error handling and configuration that are useful anyway.  Of course, there's _also_ [our new RTK Query data caching API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview), which can potentially eliminate _all_ thunks and data fetching code from your app if you choose to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess Mark's answer should be the recommended one. But, as another approach (and as a note to myself in the future), if you are not using the `createAsyncThunk` function to create your thunks, you can specify a value to be returned from a regular thunk, that you create yourself.

This is a very crude example, but would do the trick:

```
import { AnyAction, ThunkAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

type MaybeSuccess = { success: boolean }
type AppThunkMaybeSuccess = ThunkAction<Promise<MaybeSuccess>, RootState, unknown, AnyAction>;


export const someThunk = (): AppThunkMaybeSuccess => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch(SOME_THUNK_START());
    const data = await doSomeAsyncStuff(...);
    dispatch(SOME_THUNK_SUCCESS({ data }));
    return ({ success: true });
  }
  catch(err) {
    const error = err as Error;
    dispatch(SOME_THUNK_FAILURE();
    return ({ success: false });
  }
}
```

Then, on your component (the one that dispatches the thunk), you could do:

```
const handleSave = useCallback(async () => {
  const { success } = await dispatch(saveThunk());
  if (success) {
    setInputValue('');
  }
},[]);
```